# I failed to debug Laravel 8 app in Xdebug with my PhpStorm 2021.1.4

Tags: laravel, phpstorm, xdebug

I try and fail to debug my Laravel 8 app in Xdebug with my PhpStorm 2021.1.4
I have installed Xdebug in my local Ubuntu 20 OS:

```
$ php -v
PHP 8.1.4 (cli) (built: Apr  4 2022 13:30:17) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.4, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.4, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.1.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2021, by Derick Rethans
```

I added parameters in my `/etc/php/8.1/apache2/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini`:

```ini
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port=9003

xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.default_enable = 1

xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9003

implicit_flush= On

; xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
```

But I am not sure which parameters must be in this file? I searched in google and this information is different in different cases.

Running server in console :

```
php artisan serve
```

I run the app in my Chrome browser with an URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

I have installed Chrome Xdebug extension: https://prnt.sc/IBI42sSbKStr
I expected that when I refresh this page my PhpStorm will stop flow and break point will be opened.

In PhpStorm I have settings : https://prnt.sc/WgYSOlEuSjbf
with Debug port 9003 and in the file above.

and Home page break : https://prnt.sc/MSZ5KmIOYn17
and : https://prnt.sc/gKIjTXj2LlRb

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would only need the following in `20-xdebug.ini`:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=debug
```

I would however use `xdebug.mode=develop,debug` instead.

The other settings are either already the default (`xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1`, `xdebug.client_port=9003`) or for an older version (2) of Xdebug (`xdebug.remote*` and `xdebug.default_enable`).

If you install the browser extension, you still need to click the icon in it, to enable debugging.

If this does not work, then you can try debugging a page with `xdebug_info()` in it (in your index.php file, for example). This will then tell you which modes are enabled, and what Xdebug tried to do, if instructed to connect to your IDE.

If that also does not provide enough information, you can set `xdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug.log` and `xdebug.log_level=10`, and then after stopping, restarting `php artisan server`, and reloading a page in the browser it should contain a wealth of information of what went on during the start of your script, where Xdebug would check for parameters etc, and try to connect to your IDE.

Comment: Another note: he edited Apache-specific config file while uses Laravel's `artisan serve`  web server (which uses CLI config). So he may have edited the wrong .ini file.

Comment: With changes in 20-xdebug.ini I manage to stop app flow and open breakpoint in PHPStorm in case
when I set breakpoint in root public/index.php file.

If I set breakpoint in index method of my control, which in routes/web.php referenced by

    Route::resource('items', MyController::class)->except(['show']);
   
breakpoint in phpstorm is nopt opened.

Are there some other options I need to set ?